# How load two QML merging two project

Tags: c++, qt, qml, loader

I'm merging two QML\Qt project into new one and I've a problem with *.qml files.
In original projects I've a main.qml with timer, proprieties,... and a loader for bring-up the custon *.qml, to summarize: 2 folder (QML_10 and QML_15), 2 main.qml and several other qml files.
I would have a sinle project which is able to load one main or other in according to arcv[] C++ parameter.
in my C++ code :

```
QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));

if (atoi(argv[1]) == ROLE1)
    url.setUrl(QString("/QML_10/main.qml"))
else if (atoi(argv[1]) == ROLE2)
    url.setUrl(QString("/QML_15/main.qml"))
else
    printf("Error\n")
```

When I run the application I'm able to detect the right role but the setYrl doesn't work with error :

file:///QML_1/main.qml: No such file or directory

The Qt project structure is :
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `setUrl` you replace the complete content of QUrl, leading to a URL without scheme, upon which the default `file:` scheme is assumed. You should either put `qrc:` in front, or use `setPath`.

Alternatively you could use `setScheme("qrc")` afterwards.